# default_scope breaks dependent destroy behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My Miniature model has the following association:

```
class Miniature < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :minilines, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :lines, :through => :mini lines
```

This works fine but I wanted to have the Minilines sorted alphabetically by name so I added this:

```
class Miniline < ActiveRecord::Base
    default_scope { order('name ASC') }
    belongs_to :miniature
    belongs_to :line
```

I thought that was working fine but when you come to delete a Miniature you get an error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such column:
>   name: SELECT "minilines".* FROM "minilines"  WHERE
>   "minilines"."miniature_id" = ?  ORDER BY name ASC):
>   app/controllers/miniatures_controller.rb:205:in `destroy'

Removing the default_scope line allows you to delete the Miniature and has the correct behaviour.

It's not clear to me why the default_scope breaks this behaviour or how to rectify it.

My question appears to be duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337750/how-do-i-destroy-a-activemodel-instance-with-dependant-destroy-children-that-hav?rq=1) but the ticked solution there doesn't solve it for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [default\_scope breaks (update|delete|destroy)\_all in some cases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944019/default-scope-breaks-updatedeletedestroy-all-in-some-cases)

Comment: Sort of. The difference is I'm not trying to delete_all or update_all so the answers on that Q don't seem to apply to mine. I can't see an answer there that looks like it will fix my problem.

Comment: Quite strange. Are you sure there is `minilines.name` column? What does `Miniline.all` return in console?

Comment: Aha! No there isn't a mini legions.name column, it's the name column from the associated Line model. The sort works on the association but I guess it trips up the destroy somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably have:

```
default_scope { joins(:line).order('lines.name ASC') }
```

Comment: Yes! So whilst my slightly shorter default_scope code worked for the sorting it confused ActiveRecord when it came to deleting. Fair enough. This is a great solution and I didn't know you could be so precise with a joined model order. Great.